# What is the name for a single 2D polygon on a UV Mapped texture?

Tags: textures, vertex

When UV Mapping a polygon/texture, is there name that describes a single polygon on the texture.

Does this name differentiate if from the same geometry once it has been mapped to a face?

Would sometime like "UV Tile" or "UV Face" be clear?

Comment: I haven't heard of such a naming because the UV(W) coords are contained in the polygon definition, and multiple polygons can overlap and share source areas on a texture so it would get real confusing real fast.

Comment: In DirectX-terms it's "PositionTextured".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's a *"UV-mapped triangle"* or *"UV-mapped quad"*. Or simply a *"polygon with UV coordinates"*. I guess it's also fine to just call it the same as the geometry.. eg. UVs of a triangle, quad or polygon. There are some names that are introduced in UV mapping, such as *"patches"*, *"shells"* or *"islands"*, which are all names for a group of connected UV coordinates though.

A polygon doesn't get a new name once it has been UV mapped, it just gets some additional UV coordinates. So it really isn't a *"UV Tile"*.. generally you just talk about UVs (the "vertices") and "shells" or "islands" (connected UVs). If you select a polygon within UV editing, you just select and modify a bunch of UVs...